# Xamarin Tabbed Forms App Template: Spinner Does Not Stop, Async Task Void

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous, task, void

**UPDATE:** this does not occur on an Android device or Android emulator; this is an iOS device and iOS emulator specific bug.

I'm running a template right out-of-the-box on a Mac. To test yourself, you can simply go to Visual Studio:

1. File
2. New Solution
3. Multiplatform: App
4. Tabbed Forms App

When running this on an iPhone device or iPhone emulator, the spinner at the top of the list *will not stop spinning*. I suspect it is due to this code in the shared forms project:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Browse";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
            {
                var newItem = item as Item;
                Items.Add(newItem);
                await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
            });
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically, the fact that `LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemCommand())`, which, along with the method signature, is treating this like an `async Task<void>`.

I though invoking Tasks as void was a big **no-no** because, among other reasons, the CLR state machine can't do anything with the result(s) of the task? Additionally, anything that this task changes that is being watched by some delegate, notable `IsBusy`, will not be impacted?

From **BaseViewModel.cs**:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();

    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }
 ...
}
```

From the view, specifically the spinner control, **ItemsPage.xaml**:

`IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"`

**MacOS:** 10.15.2,
**Visual Studio for Mac:** 8.3.10 (Build 2),
**Xcode:** 11.3 (11C29),
**iOS Simulator:** 11.3 (SimulatorApp-912.5 SimulatorKit-570.3 CoreSimulator-681.17)

Comment: Excuse me, according to the steps you mentioned, there is no control you mentioned `the spinner at the top of the list `. Could you please explain it in details?

Comment: There is a wait/busy spinner that is at the top of the list of items. For example, if you “pull down” on the list to initiate a reload/refresh, you’ll see a spinner.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Please see above

Comment: Ok,I got it.  I tested with iPhone emulator, but it works properly.  I tested on Visual studio 2019. xamarin Form 4.3.0.908675 .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT We have two developers on latest of Visual Studio, .NET, Xamarin, XCode, and MacOS. Both having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry,I tested this problem by creating sample on  windows10 and connecting to a iPhone emulator. And I will try to test on MAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the following within the Forms and iOS projects,

- Xamarin.Forms (4.2.0.709249) -> (4.4.0.991265)
- Xamarin.Essentials
  (1.2.0) -> (1.3.1)

the spinner now stops spinning once the list is loaded. It should be noted that when these projects are being created, despite Visual Studio being up-to-date, it is choosing to create said projects with dated NuGet packages.